# Python - Link Requests library to my browser

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python Requests library to get some informations out of Amazon.
This is my current problem: let's say I add something to the cart (without authentication), I can see that now there is an item in my cart and if I inspect element I can see field modified but if I start the script now Requests takes the static field with 0 items in the cart. I would like to link my browser and my physical actions with this library.

I hope I explained myself. Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you please give us a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: you have to use `requests.Session()` to maintain the session during your request

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη It doesn't seem to work for the purpose that I stated in the question